# Returning an array with decimal values in a javascript function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

im having trouble returning an array that contains decimal values to a variable:

```
function foo() {
    var coords = new Array(39.3,18.2);
    console.log(coords[1]); //successfully logs 18.2
    return coords;
}
```

but then...

```
var result = foo();
alert(result[0]);
```

that last one throws this error:
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined**

Comment: Shouldn't that be `alert(result[0])`? Everything else looks fine - I'd say the problem is somewhere else in your code.

Comment: That's not the issue. Ill correct the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As other people mentioned, alert is a function and needs parenthesis

```
alert(result[0])
```

That said, there are some extra points to note:

1) Use array literal syntax instead of `new Array`

```
var coords = [1.23, 3.45];
```

Its faster and new Array has some edge cases.

2) Most browsers have developer tools (usually reacheable by F12). This allows you to use the much more convenient console.log instead of alert.

Comment: what if i need to fill that array in a foreach loop?

Comment: @andufo: What does have to do with how you create the array? After the array is created they work just the same.

Answer (score 4):

You need to put parentheses around the argument to the alert function.

```
alert(result[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the missing parentheses around the alert statment

try

```
alert (result[0]);
```